# How to inflate a custom layout and edit your views in this case?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am following [this tutorial](https://android.jlelse.eu/get-expandable-recyclerview-in-a-simple-way-8946046b4573) to create an expandable recyclerview. The source code is [here](https://github.com/RohitSurwase/AndroidDesignPatterns/tree/master/dynamic-recycler-view).My goal is to inflate this view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/roundedImageView"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:riv_corner_radius="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        tools:text="This is a textview" />
</LinearLayout>
```

instead of a textview here:

```
for (int indexView = 0; indexView < intMaxNoOfChild; indexView++) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setId(indexView);
    textView.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 20);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.background_sub_module_text));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linearLayout_childItems.addView(textView, layoutParams);
}
```

How can I do this and set a text and image for each view? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need a [LayoutInflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater) to be able to inflate custom layouts. There are a few overrides for the `inflate` function that you can use to inflate your custom layouts

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_name, parent, false)
```